# d3 queue with double click

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

So what I want to do is use the 
`d3.queue()`
function to load one of the JSON data when the user double clicks.

So I have two JSON files

`graphs.json, shelf.json`

The code so far

```
// queue the file
var q = d3.queue();
q.defer(d3.json, "shelf.json").await(ready);

// Load the first file
d3.json("graphs.json", function(data)
    {
     // Lots of code here 

    chars
        .on("dblclick", function(d, i) {

            if (this.className.split(' ').indexOf('open') > -1) {
                d3.select(this).classed("open", false).transition().style("height", "100px").style("width", "100px").style("z-index", "1");
            } else {
                function ready() {if (error) throw error;}

                d3.selectAll(".gridData" + d.x + d.y).classed("open", false);
                d3.selectAll(".gridData" + d.x + d.y).style("grid-row-start", "1");
                d3.selectAll(".gridData" + d.x + d.y).style("grid-column-start", "1");
                d3.select(this).classed("open", true);
                d3.select(this).transition().style("height", "700px").style("width", "900px").style("top", "0").style("left", "0").style("z-index", "1000000");

            }
        });
    }
```

On the double click I would like it to call the shelf.json file. Putting a function inside the double click to respond to the double click doesn't work and I would only want the double click to work when loading up that element. So not when double clicking outside of the element. Is there a simple syntax I am missing or is this more complicated than it seems?

Comment: Why doesn't putting the `ready` function inside the double click function work? Can you define that function outside and call it inside?

Comment: It doesn't find the ready function and I get the error. if I define that function outside wouldn't it load up the JSON files prior to the doubleclick

Comment: you can define the function at the top level without calling it. that way, the function inside `.on('dblclick'` and the `.await` should both have it in scope

Comment: I think that was relatively simple, don't know why I just didn't put that together. Thank you.